# Merging two CSV files in Powershell but some output entries are doubled with missing data

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, pscustomobject

I am currently in the process of setting up a file upload for a work project. The uploaded file should contain all items with the necessary data and all variations (eg. size or length). The problem is, I can't export the variation data in the same file as the general item data so I figured since I already handle the processing and upload with a powershell script, I could merge those two files before uploading the result with powershell as well.

Here are the headers for both CSV-Files:

```
feed_file
Artikelnummer,EAN,Hersteller,Produktname,EKPreis,UVP,Produktbeschreibung,ProduktURL,BildURL,Bestand

variant_file
"VaterArtikelnummer";"Artikelnummer";"UVP";"Bestand";"Variationsname1";"Variationsname2";"Variationsname3";"Variationswertname1";"Variationswertname2";"Variationswertname3";"EKPreis"
```

"Artikelnummer" is the common key for both files as it contains unique numbers that only appear once per file and most (but not all) entries in the variant file are also present in the basic feed file.

Here is the code for the merging process (as it is currently not working, it is still contained in its own file so there is no other code that could be interfering with it):

```
# Set the base path for the script and all relevant files
$path = "C:/path/to/files/and/script"

# Get the most recent item and variation csv files and import them
$feed_file = Import-Csv (get-childitem -path "$path/files/article/*" -Include *.csv | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1)
$variant_file = Import-Csv (get-childitem -path "$path/jtlExport/*" -Include Export_*.csv | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1) -Delimiter ";"

<# Generate an output where the following is true:
    - Any item that is not a variant (not in $variant_file) gets assigned the already present data from $feed_file and appropriate empty columns at the end
    - Any item that is a variant gets assigned the full data set, including any information about the variant
#>
$output = Foreach($item in $feed_file){
    $variant_file | Where-Object Artikelnummer -eq $item.Artikelnummer -ov result
    If(-not $result){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Artikelnummer = $item.Artikelnummer
            EAN = $item.EAN
            Hersteller = $item.Hersteller
            Produktname = $item.Produktname
            EKPreis = $item.EKPreis
            UVP = $item.UVP
            Produktbeschreibung = $item.Produktbeschreibung
            ProduktURL = $item.ProduktURL
            BildURL = $item.BildURL
            Bestand = $item.Bestand
            VaterArtikelnummer = ""
            Variationsname1 = ""
            Variationsname2 = ""
            Variationsname3 = ""
            Variationswertname1 = ""
            Variationswertname2 = ""
            Variationswertname3 = ""
        }
    }
    Else{
        Foreach($variant in $variant_file){
            If($item.Artikelnummer -eq $variant.Artikelnummer){
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Artikelnummer = $item.Artikelnummer
                    EAN = $item.EAN
                    Hersteller = $item.Hersteller
                    Produktname = $item.Produktname
                    EKPreis = $item.EKPreis
                    UVP = $item.UVP
                    Produktbeschreibung = $item.Produktbeschreibung
                    ProduktURL = $item.ProduktURL
                    BildURL = $item.BildURL
                    Bestand = $item.Bestand
                    VaterArtikelnummer = $variant.VaterArtikelnummer
                    Variationsname1 = $variant.Variationsname1
                    Variationsname2 = $variant.Variationsname2
                    Variationsname3 = $variant.Variationsname3
                    Variationswertname1 = $variant.Variationswertname1
                    Variationswertname2 = $variant.Variationswertname2
                    Variationswertname3 = $variant.Variationswertname3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Export the output as a csv file ready to upload
$output | Export-Csv -Path "$path/sample.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

While the code in general can most likely be improved massively, I am just happy that it is doing what I want it to do after spending quite a while scouring the internet to find a way to merge the two files that worked in my case (though I'd still appreciate any tips and suggestions).

Though there is one issue which I simply can't seem to figure out, although the output is handled the way I want it, there is an issue that every item that is a variant, ends up twice in the final output, but one of the entries is missing most of the data. Here is an example:

```
"12345678_9",,,,"388,7","894,00",,,,"1","12345678","Größe","","","58","",""
"12345678_9","3210987654321","Hersteller","Produktname","388.70","894","Beschreibung","ProduktURL","BildURL","0","12345678","Größe","","","58","",""
```

As you can see, the first entry in the output file (for every single item which has variant data) is a stripped down version, missing most of the original data while still keeping some. My first guess was that the item somehow is listed twice but if I check the original two input files that were used, I can only find one entry in either file for any of the items, no doubles anywhere.

I also tried changing the first part of my code (for any items without variant data) to output a fixed string in certain columns and while this had an effect on any item that isn't a variant, the double still had empty columns in that place so I would assume it must have to do with the latter part handling the items that do have matching variant data but I just can't get behind what exactly is causing this issue.

I am using Powershell 5.1 on a Windows Server 2016, I hope someone can show me the probably obvious answer to this issue. 
Thank you all in advance for your help!

Best regards

-Kevin

Edit: The solution provided by Hansson0728 worked perfectly, with the minor adjustment of the type "AllInLeft" but it also seems to be a lot faster than my bulky manual method.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/3.2.1) cmdlet: `$feed_file | Merge $Variant -On ArtikelNummer`, see also: [In PowerShel, what is the best way to join two tables in one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$feedFile = import-csv <File>
$Variant = import-csv <File>
```

Try With this function and do something like

---

```
$feedFile | Join-Object -Right $variant_file -LeftJoinProperty ArtikelNummer -RightJoinProperty ArtikelNummer -Type OnlyIfInBoth
```

---

```
  function Join-Object {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Join data from two sets of objects based on a common value

    .DESCRIPTION
        Join data from two sets of objects based on a common value

        For more details, see the accompanying blog post:
            http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/

        For even more details,  see the original code and discussions that this borrows from:
            Dave Wyatt's Join-Object - http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/merging-very-large-collections
            Lucio Silveira's Join-Object - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx

    .PARAMETER Left
        'Left' collection of objects to join.  You can use the pipeline for Left.

        The objects in this collection should be consistent.
        We look at the properties on the first object for a baseline.

    .PARAMETER Right
        'Right' collection of objects to join.

        The objects in this collection should be consistent.
        We look at the properties on the first object for a baseline.

    .PARAMETER LeftJoinProperty
        Property on Left collection objects that we match up with RightJoinProperty on the Right collection

    .PARAMETER RightJoinProperty
        Property on Right collection objects that we match up with LeftJoinProperty on the Left collection

    .PARAMETER LeftProperties
        One or more properties to keep from Left.  Default is to keep all Left properties (*).

        Each property can:
            - Be a plain property name like "Name"
            - Contain wildcards like "*"
            - Be a hashtable like @{Name="Product Name";Expression={$_.Name}}.
                 Name is the output property name
                 Expression is the property value ($_ as the current object)

                 Alternatively, use the Suffix or Prefix parameter to avoid collisions
                 Each property using this hashtable syntax will be excluded from suffixes and prefixes

    .PARAMETER RightProperties
        One or more properties to keep from Right.  Default is to keep all Right properties (*).

        Each property can:
            - Be a plain property name like "Name"
            - Contain wildcards like "*"
            - Be a hashtable like @{Name="Product Name";Expression={$_.Name}}.
                 Name is the output property name
                 Expression is the property value ($_ as the current object)

                 Alternatively, use the Suffix or Prefix parameter to avoid collisions
                 Each property using this hashtable syntax will be excluded from suffixes and prefixes

    .PARAMETER Prefix
        If specified, prepend Right object property names with this prefix to avoid collisions

        Example:
            Property Name                   = 'Name'
            Suffix                          = 'j_'
            Resulting Joined Property Name  = 'j_Name'

    .PARAMETER Suffix
        If specified, append Right object property names with this suffix to avoid collisions

        Example:
            Property Name                   = 'Name'
            Suffix                          = '_j'
            Resulting Joined Property Name  = 'Name_j'

    .PARAMETER Type
        Type of join.  Default is AllInLeft.

        AllInLeft will have all elements from Left at least once in the output, and might appear more than once
          if the where clause is true for more than one element in right, Left elements with matches in Right are
          preceded by elements with no matches.
          SQL equivalent: outer left join (or simply left join)

        AllInRight is similar to AllInLeft.

        OnlyIfInBoth will cause all elements from Left to be placed in the output, only if there is at least one
          match in Right.
          SQL equivalent: inner join (or simply join)

        AllInBoth will have all entries in right and left in the output. Specifically, it will have all entries
          in right with at least one match in left, followed by all entries in Right with no matches in left, 
          followed by all entries in Left with no matches in Right.
          SQL equivalent: full join

    .EXAMPLE
        #
        #Define some input data.

        $l = 1..5 | Foreach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Name = "jsmith$_"
                Birthday = (Get-Date).adddays(-1)
            }
        }

        $r = 4..7 | Foreach-Object{
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Department = "Department $_"
                Name = "Department $_"
                Manager = "jsmith$_"
            }
        }

        #We have a name and Birthday for each manager, how do we find their department, using an inner join?
        Join-Object -Left $l -Right $r -LeftJoinProperty Name -RightJoinProperty Manager -Type OnlyIfInBoth -RightProperties Department


            # Name    Birthday             Department  
            # ----    --------             ----------  
            # jsmith4 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM Department 4
            # jsmith5 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM Department 5

    .EXAMPLE  
        #
        #Define some input data.

        $l = 1..5 | Foreach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Name = "jsmith$_"
                Birthday = (Get-Date).adddays(-1)
            }
        }

        $r = 4..7 | Foreach-Object{
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Department = "Department $_"
                Name = "Department $_"
                Manager = "jsmith$_"
            }
        }

        #We have a name and Birthday for each manager, how do we find all related department data, even if there are conflicting properties?
        $l | Join-Object -Right $r -LeftJoinProperty Name -RightJoinProperty Manager -Type AllInLeft -Prefix j_

            # Name    Birthday             j_Department j_Name       j_Manager
            # ----    --------             ------------ ------       ---------
            # jsmith1 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM                                    
            # jsmith2 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM                                    
            # jsmith3 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM                                    
            # jsmith4 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM Department 4 Department 4 jsmith4  
            # jsmith5 4/14/2015 3:27:22 PM Department 5 Department 5 jsmith5  

    .EXAMPLE
        #
        #Hey!  You know how to script right?  Can you merge these two CSVs, where Path1's IP is equal to Path2's IP_ADDRESS?

        #Get CSV data
        $s1 = Import-CSV $Path1
        $s2 = Import-CSV $Path2

        #Merge the data, using a full outer join to avoid omitting anything, and export it
        Join-Object -Left $s1 -Right $s2 -LeftJoinProperty IP_ADDRESS -RightJoinProperty IP -Prefix 'j_' -Type AllInBoth |
            Export-CSV $MergePath -NoTypeInformation

    .EXAMPLE
        #
        # "Hey Warren, we need to match up SSNs to Active Directory users, and check if they are enabled or not.
        #  I'll e-mail you an unencrypted CSV with all the SSNs from gmail, what could go wrong?"

        # Import some SSNs. 
        $SSNs = Import-CSV -Path D:\SSNs.csv

        #Get AD users, and match up by a common value, samaccountname in this case:
        Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -like 'wframe*'" |
            Join-Object -LeftJoinProperty samaccountname -Right $SSNs `
                        -RightJoinProperty samaccountname -RightProperties ssn `
                        -LeftProperties samaccountname, enabled, objectclass

    .NOTES
        This borrows from:
            Dave Wyatt's Join-Object - http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/merging-very-large-collections/
            Lucio Silveira's Join-Object - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx

        Changes:
            Always display full set of properties
            Display properties in order (left first, right second)
            If specified, add suffix or prefix to right object property names to avoid collisions
            Use a hashtable rather than ordereddictionary (avoid case sensitivity)

    .LINK
        http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/

    .FUNCTIONALITY
        PowerShell Language

    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLine = $true)]
        [object[]] $Left,

        # List to join with $Left
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [object[]] $Right,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $LeftJoinProperty,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $RightJoinProperty,

        [object[]]$LeftProperties = '*',

        # Properties from $Right we want in the output.
        # Like LeftProperties, each can be a plain name, wildcard or hashtable. See the LeftProperties comments.
        [object[]]$RightProperties = '*',

        [validateset( 'AllInLeft', 'OnlyIfInBoth', 'AllInBoth', 'AllInRight')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Type = 'AllInLeft',

        [string]$Prefix,
        [string]$Suffix
    )
    Begin
    {
        function AddItemProperties($item, $properties, $hash)
        {
            if ($null -eq $item)
            {
                return
            }

            foreach($property in $properties)
            {
                $propertyHash = $property -as [hashtable]
                if($null -ne $propertyHash)
                {
                    $hashName = $propertyHash["name"] -as [string]         
                    $expression = $propertyHash["expression"] -as [scriptblock]

                    $expressionValue = $expression.Invoke($item)[0]

                    $hash[$hashName] = $expressionValue
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($itemProperty in $item.psobject.Properties)
                    {
                        if ($itemProperty.Name -like $property)
                        {
                            $hash[$itemProperty.Name] = $itemProperty.Value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function TranslateProperties
        {
            [cmdletbinding()]
            param(
                [object[]]$Properties,
                [psobject]$RealObject,
                [string]$Side)

            foreach($Prop in $Properties)
            {
                $propertyHash = $Prop -as [hashtable]
                if($null -ne $propertyHash)
                {
                    $hashName = $propertyHash["name"] -as [string]         
                    $expression = $propertyHash["expression"] -as [scriptblock]

                    $ScriptString = $expression.tostring()
                    if($ScriptString -notmatch 'param\(')
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Property '$HashName'`: Adding param(`$_) to scriptblock '$ScriptString'"
                        $Expression = [ScriptBlock]::Create("param(`$_)`n $ScriptString")
                    }

                    $Output = @{Name =$HashName; Expression = $Expression }
                    Write-Verbose "Found $Side property hash with name $($Output.Name), expression:`n$($Output.Expression | out-string)"
                    $Output
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($ThisProp in $RealObject.psobject.Properties)
                    {
                        if ($ThisProp.Name -like $Prop)
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Found $Side property '$($ThisProp.Name)'"
                            $ThisProp.Name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function WriteJoinObjectOutput($leftItem, $rightItem, $leftProperties, $rightProperties)
        {
            $properties = @{}

            AddItemProperties $leftItem $leftProperties $properties
            AddItemProperties $rightItem $rightProperties $properties

            New-Object psobject -Property $properties
        }

        #Translate variations on calculated properties.  Doing this once shouldn't affect perf too much.
        foreach($Prop in @($LeftProperties + $RightProperties))
        {
            if($Prop -as [hashtable])
            {
                foreach($variation in ('n','label','l'))
                {
                    if(-not $Prop.ContainsKey('Name') )
                    {
                        if($Prop.ContainsKey($variation) )
                        {
                            $Prop.Add('Name',$Prop[$Variation])
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(-not $Prop.ContainsKey('Name') -or $Prop['Name'] -like $null )
                {
                    Throw "Property is missing a name`n. This should be in calculated property format, with a Name and an Expression:`n@{Name='Something';Expression={`$_.Something}}`nAffected property:`n$($Prop | out-string)"
                }


                if(-not $Prop.ContainsKey('Expression') )
                {
                    if($Prop.ContainsKey('E') )
                    {
                        $Prop.Add('Expression',$Prop['E'])
                    }
                }

                if(-not $Prop.ContainsKey('Expression') -or $Prop['Expression'] -like $null )
                {
                    Throw "Property is missing an expression`n. This should be in calculated property format, with a Name and an Expression:`n@{Name='Something';Expression={`$_.Something}}`nAffected property:`n$($Prop | out-string)"
                }
            }        
        }

        $leftHash = @{}
        $rightHash = @{}

        # Hashtable keys can't be null; we'll use any old object reference as a placeholder if needed.
        $nullKey = New-Object psobject

        $bound = $PSBoundParameters.keys -contains "InputObject"
        if(-not $bound)
        {
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$LeftData = @()
        }
    }
    Process
    {
        #We pull all the data for comparison later, no streaming
        if($bound)
        {
            $LeftData = $Left
        }
        Else
        {
            foreach($Object in $Left)
            {
                [void]$LeftData.add($Object)
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        foreach ($item in $Right)
        {
            $key = $item.$RightJoinProperty

            if ($null -eq $key)
            {
                $key = $nullKey
            }

            $bucket = $rightHash[$key]

            if ($null -eq $bucket)
            {
                $bucket = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
                $rightHash.Add($key, $bucket)
            }

            $null = $bucket.Add($item)
        }

        foreach ($item in $LeftData)
        {
            $key = $item.$LeftJoinProperty

            if ($null -eq $key)
            {
                $key = $nullKey
            }

            $bucket = $leftHash[$key]

            if ($null -eq $bucket)
            {
                $bucket = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
                $leftHash.Add($key, $bucket)
            }

            $null = $bucket.Add($item)
        }

        $LeftProperties = TranslateProperties -Properties $LeftProperties -Side 'Left' -RealObject $LeftData[0]
        $RightProperties = TranslateProperties -Properties $RightProperties -Side 'Right' -RealObject $Right[0]

        #I prefer ordered output. Left properties first.
        [string[]]$AllProps = $LeftProperties

        #Handle prefixes, suffixes, and building AllProps with Name only
        $RightProperties = foreach($RightProp in $RightProperties)
        {
            if(-not ($RightProp -as [Hashtable]))
            {
                Write-Verbose "Transforming property $RightProp to $Prefix$RightProp$Suffix"
                @{
                    Name="$Prefix$RightProp$Suffix"
                    Expression=[scriptblock]::create("param(`$_) `$_.'$RightProp'")
                }
                $AllProps += "$Prefix$RightProp$Suffix"
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Verbose "Skipping transformation of calculated property with name $($RightProp.Name), expression:`n$($RightProp.Expression | out-string)"
                $AllProps += [string]$RightProp["Name"]
                $RightProp
            }
        }

        $AllProps = $AllProps | Select -Unique

        Write-Verbose "Combined set of properties: $($AllProps -join ', ')"

        foreach ( $entry in $leftHash.GetEnumerator() )
        {
            $key = $entry.Key
            $leftBucket = $entry.Value

            $rightBucket = $rightHash[$key]

            if ($null -eq $rightBucket)
            {
                if ($Type -eq 'AllInLeft' -or $Type -eq 'AllInBoth')
                {
                    foreach ($leftItem in $leftBucket)
                    {
                        WriteJoinObjectOutput $leftItem $null $LeftProperties $RightProperties | Select $AllProps
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($leftItem in $leftBucket)
                {
                    foreach ($rightItem in $rightBucket)
                    {
                        WriteJoinObjectOutput $leftItem $rightItem $LeftProperties $RightProperties | Select $AllProps
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($Type -eq 'AllInRight' -or $Type -eq 'AllInBoth')
        {
            foreach ($entry in $rightHash.GetEnumerator())
            {
                $key = $entry.Key
                $rightBucket = $entry.Value

                $leftBucket = $leftHash[$key]

                if ($null -eq $leftBucket)
                {
                    foreach ($rightItem in $rightBucket)
                    {
                        WriteJoinObjectOutput $null $rightItem $LeftProperties $RightProperties | Select $AllProps
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```